# Can we start a question with pronouns?

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions, pronouns, auxiliary-verbs

**Starting questions with pronouns**

Forex.
"I have to do this assignment in my notebook or on my computer?"

Can we write a question like this or it is incorrect?

Comment: Are you asking if  English language can form questions without subject-auxiliary inversion?

Comment: Yes, I also want to ask whether this sentence makes any sense or not.

Comment: Normally you would begin a question with _Do I have to...?_ In speech, it's possible to turn a statement into a question by using a different tone of voice, but obviously this isn't possible in writing.